# directive not updating on watch (or watchCollection)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to have a directive which updates when a collection receives an update, but can't seem to get the watch event (or `$watchCollection`) to trigger.

In my factory, I have a collection

```
var streams = {
     "main":{ stream: streamDetails},
     "guest":{ stream: streamDetails}
}
```

which I include in my controller via

```
.controller('vidCtrl', function($scope, vidFactory){
     $scope.streams = vidFactory.streams;
});
```

In my html, I have

```
<stream data-name="main"></stream>
<stream data-name="guest"></stream>
<stream data-name="other"></stream>
```

The directive which manages the videos is

```
app.directive('stream', function(){
       return {
             restrict: 'E',
             template: '<video></video>',
             scope:{
               name: '='
             },
             link: function(scope, element, attr){
              if(!scope.streams[scope.name]) return console.log('video not ready');
              var vid = scope.streams[scope.name];
               var video = element.find('video');
               video.attr('src', vid.stream);
               video[0].play();
             }
       }
});
```

What I'm trying to do is have the `other` stream added to the `$scope.streams` and then have it show up in the correct tag.

I was hoping that in my directive I would add

```
scope.$watchCollection('videos', function(){
      //update stream somehow
});
```

But unfortunately, when I add a new video to the videos object, the `$watchCollection` isn't being triggered.

I'm adding to the `vidFactory.videos` via the below function, which I can verify is updating the collection correctly. Of course, being in the factory, I can't use `$scope.$apply()`, and if I put the .on method in the controller, it triggers multiple times because the controller is included in a few different angular directives.

```
qc.on('video:added', function(stream){
    streams[stream.name] = stream;
});
```

I've also tried watching for a specific stream instead of `$watchCollection` via

```
if(!scope.streams[scope.name]){
 scope.streams[scope.name]=null;
 scope.$watch(scope.streams[scope.name], function(){
   //add video to stream method would go here
 }, true);
```

I think the using watch is preferred to `$watchCollection`, but I can't figure out why my controller isn't triggering the `$watch`.

Comment: Try to make a http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: Where is `scope.videos` initialized?

Comment: @Jerrad, scope.videos is initialized in the controller, sorry, I called it scope.streams here. I'll update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access `scope.streams` as if it were defined in your directive's scope.

But, since your directive uses an isolate scope, it does not inherit `streams` from its parent scope.

You could pass it to the directive like this:

```
<stream data-streams="streams" data-name="other"></stream>

app.directive('stream', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<video></video>',
        scope: {
            streams: '=',
            name: '@'
        },
        ...
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/P92dG/)**.

Comment: I initially thought you were on to something @ExpertSystem, and you very well may be, but when including the streams in the directive scope, I get a non-assignable expression error https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign

Comment: Are you sure you used my code ? Can you prepare a fiddle or plunkr ?

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle. When I click 'add stream' it adds the 'other' stream to the streams object, but doesn't update the directive. $apply gives me a digest error. Not sure why I'm not getting the noassign error now.

Comment: @pedalpete: Where's the fiddle ?

Comment: OH DAMNIT!! I forgot to copy it. Now it's gone forever... I got the issue sorted out by putting my other watchers inside the scope, and if the data coming in isn't for that div, I don't continue.

Comment: Regarding jsFiddle: You can 1. Look in your browser's history for recently visited pages or closed tabs. 2. Create an account on jsFiddle, so you don't lose your fiddles :)

Comment: I found the fiddle, here it is . http://jsfiddle.net/FpgU4/1/, Thanks. 
At the same time, I've solved my problem, but still not sure why your solution wasn't working.

Comment: @pedalpete: I updated the fiddle and added it to my answer for reference. The reason why `$watchCollection` wasn't working was, of course, that you never specified a `$watchCollection`...

Comment: I couldn't find your fiddle update, but here is mine. http://jsfiddle.net/FpgU4/2/. You are correct, it is working now. I'm not sure what I was seeing before, but I thought I was getting errors before even getting to the $watchCollection piece. Thanks. Accepting your answer now